# Change ListView Height at Runtime

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am trying to implement a nested ListView at the bottom of my UI but only one item of my array is populating the screen. I've figured out that I can display all of my items if I set my Height attribute (i.e. "175dp" in lieu of "Wrap_Content"). The problem is the list size is not static, so I need to adjust the height of my ListView at runtime.

I've dug around the internets and here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks!

Code from my fragment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    list.add(values[i]);
}

final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(rootView.getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_linear).getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout manager = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_linear);
lp.height = 45 * values.length;
manager.setLayoutParams(lp);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#BBDEFB"
android:padding="3dp"
android:id="@+id/movie_description_container">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_hero_image"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:src="@drawable/sample_1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="movie title"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/movie_detail_hero_image"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    android:textSize="36dp"
    android:textColor="#BBDEFB"
    android:background="#a3000000"
    android:layout_above="@id/movie_detail_hero_image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="18dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_poster"
    android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_detail_title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="date"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_date"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/movie_detail_hero_image"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movie_detail_hero_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Rating:"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_rating"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_detail_date"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movie_detail_date"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/movie_detail_date"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:maxWidth="77dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_detail_rating"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movie_detail_rating"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/movie_detail_rating"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Synopsis"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_synopsis_header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_detail_poster"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movie_detail_poster"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movie_detail_poster" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="description"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_synopsis"
    android:layout_below="@+id/movie_detail_synopsis_header"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movie_detail_synopsis_header"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movie_detail_synopsis_header"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton_Favorite"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
    android:maxWidth="45dp"
    android:maxHeight="45dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_linear"
    android:layout_below="@id/movie_detail_synopsis">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"

        android:id="@+id/list_view2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have not set an orientation to the LinearLayout containing your list view. Default is horizontal. Also, the list view is scrollable. You don't have to make the list higher to make room for more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can set the height of listview to the size of childers with this method

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```